# Can't Unlink Form Google App Script "Err: Failed to remove form's destination. Please wait and try again."

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I used to use Google App Script to Unlink Forms pretty well but it's not anymore by now. The App Script return "Err: Failed to remove form's destination. Please wait and try again." all the time. Is there anyone experience this case?

removeDestination() used to work well until 2-3 days ago. I can't use it anymore.

```
formResponses = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetId)
for (let sht of sheets) {
let formUrl = sht.getFormUrl();
if (formUrl != null) {
  let theForm = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  let formID = theForm.getId();
  try {
    theForm.removeDestination();
    formResponses.deleteSheet(sht);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    DriveApp.getFileById(formID).setTrashed(true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Can\'t delete ' + theForm.getTitle() + ' due to ' + e);
    done = false
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code is incomplete.  formResponses is undefined.

Comment: Actually formResponses was already defined by formResponses = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetId)

Comment: sheets is undefined.  Code is still incomplete

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error when testing with my forms.

Someone filed a public issue in Google's public issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/189445039

Add a star next to the issue number to indicate you are affected by it too.